# Prove that $F_{\sum_{i=1}^ka_i}\geq \prod_{i=1}^kF_{a_i}\forall a_i,k \geq 1$

Tags: inequality, fibonacci-numbers

Is there an elegant way to do this? I don't think it's particularly difficult, since $F_n \sim \frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$, so we expect that $F_{\sum_{i=1}^ka_i} \sim \frac{\phi^{\sum_{i=1}^ka_i}}{\sqrt{5}}$, while $\prod_{i=1}^kF_{a_i} \sim \frac{\phi^{\sum_{i=1}^ka_i}}{5^{k/2}}$. However, I don't know how to show that the error is small enough or if some other approach would be simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to prove it for $k=2$. Using an identity mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form) you can write $$F_m F_n<F_m F_n + F_{m-1}F_{n-1}=F_{m+n-1}<F_{m+n}.$$